# How do I get an answer by its id using Cyc Java API?

Tags: opencyc

I am building a web service, which will return the proof of the answer to the client. The only way I can retrieve an answer using Java Cyc API is to get it by its index in the answers list. I am not sure if it is a proper and safe way to do it.
How do I get an answer by its id using Cyc Java API?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there's no way to get an answer from just the ID.  You have to hold on to the query object, and ask the query object for the answer.  If you have the query object and you want answer 20 from that query, you can get the answer itself straightforwardly by calling

`q.getAnswer(20)`